# Error: Could not undump 19094 4-byte item(s) from /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt

Tags: pdftex

I am getting this error usuing latex files that I know they work:

```
latex Thesis.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
latex: fatal: Could not undump 19094 4-byte item(s) from /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt.
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

I have already tried

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

and did not solve it... I have also try to reinstall texlive and that did not solve it either. I am using:

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you checked that after `fmutil-sys --all`, the file `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt` has been updated? Maybe it's a path problem, i.e., maybe pdftex searches the fmt file in the wrong place. This might happen if you have installed Debian tex packages alongside a separate texlive installation under `\usr\local`.

Comment: I have removed them and run again $sudo fmtutil-sys --all. Still same problem,  I am using UBUNTU and I used thu usual $ sudo apt install texlive-full on it. So, it should be standard path on UBUNTU

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.10
Release: 20.10
Codename: groovy